# Where mysql puede ser null

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Hecho esto de ejemplo, como vereis en el select busco el id la oferta, el nombre del cliente, y el estado de la oferta.

Dicha query el estado ha de ser **2**. Como puedo añadir al where para que el cliente pueda ser null. Ya se que pido el nombre del cliente y si es null no tendra, eso es lo que quiero. Que me digan todas las ofertas con estado 2 tengan o no cliente. El problema es que en caso de tener cliente he de saber el nombre

```
create table clientes(Cliente_id integer primary key, Nombre varchar(50), 
Direccion varchar(100), NIF integer);
create table ofertas(id integer primary key, codigo_oferta 
integer,cliente_id integer, fecha date, estado integer, 
CONSTRAINT fk_Cliente FOREIGN KEY (cliente_id) REFERENCES clientes 
(Cliente_id));

show tables;

insert into clientes values (1,'Luis','asdaddasdsda',23858870);
insert into clientes values (2,"Maria","Daigonal 234",12345678);

insert into ofertas values (1,00001,1,default,2);
insert into ofertas values (2,00002,1,default,1);
insert into ofertas values (3,00003,null,default,2);
insert into ofertas values (4,00004,null,default,1);

Select O.id, C.Nombre, O.estado from ofertas O, clientes C where 
C.Cliente_id = O.cliente_id  and O.estado = 2 \G
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He hecho la siguiente prueba y me ha funcionado.

Simplemente, haces un left join hacia la tabla clientes relacionando por cliente_id.

```
SELECT O.id, C.Nombre, O.estado FROM ofertas O
    LEFT JOIN clientes C ON c.cliente_id = o.cliente_id
WHERE O.estado = 2
```

Y el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy buena lo habia medio conseguido añadiendo **where C.Cliente_id = O.cliente_id or O.cliente_id = null** pero la segunda row del select me seguia saliendo el nombre de la primera. Muchas Gracias, no entiendo muy bien el join

Comment: El Left Join quiere decir que das prioridad a los resultados de la primera tabla (Ofertas), combinando los resultados con la tabla de la derecha (Clientes) relacionandolos con el campo cliente_id. En caso que algún registro de la relación es null, da igual, tu los quieres todos (por eso das prioridad a la tabla izquierda, la de Ofertas), y aquí es donde entra en juego el where. En resumen, el left join es: dame los registros de la tabla "Ofertas", relacionado con la tabla "Clientes" cuya relación es cliente_id que tengan el estado = 2. Si tiene cliente_id, muestramelo, y si no, también ;)

Comment: gracias por la explicación!!

Comment: He editado mi comentario para que lo entiendas aun mejor ;)